# Font awesome not showing in Bootstrap 4 navbar-brand

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm trying to set up a local Laravel website to learn the new features and differences in Laravel 5.6. However, when trying to place a Font Awesome icon in the `navbar-brand` in Bootstrap 4 it won't seem to load. When I check out the element in the inspector in Chrome the elements dimensions are 0x0. I tried adding width and height of 90px just to see the icon but it still won't show. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="{{ route('/') }}" class="navbar-brand">
        <i class="fa fa-laptop-code"></i>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="{{ Auth::check() ? route('home') : route('/') }}" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- NAVBAR -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fa-laptop-code` is not available in the version of font-awesome you are loading.

You are loading 4.7, but if you want to use that icon you need to load FontAwesome 5

Use this CDN instead: https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css

Comment: Yep, this worked. I just snagged the font-awesome CDN from the Bootstrap website. Didn't expect it to be out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work

```
<i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
```

Comment: Although this worked it didn't exactly solve my problem because I can't use the icon I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="{{ route('/') }}" class="navbar-brand">
        <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="{{ Auth::check() ? route('home') : route('/') }}" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- NAVBAR -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```